How to create a measure in QlikSense to count distinct equipment sending signals within a dynamic date range
I'm working with a dataset in QlikSense that tracks daily equipment signal data. Each record includes the equipment ID (serial_number), the date the signal was sent (created_on), and the date the equipment first sent a signal (first_signal). My goal is to create two measures:

Measure 1: Count the number of distinct equipment (serial_number)
sending data on a given date (created_on).
Measure 2: Count the number of distinct equipment that have sent
their first signal on or before the given date (created_on).

I want to have a table where

dimension is the created_on date,
"distinct daily serial numbers" is one column and
"all active equipments" is the third column.

Here is a simplified example of my dataset:



serial_number
created_on
first_signal




EQM1
2024-03-01
2024-03-01


EQM1
2024-03-02
2024-03-01


EQM1
2024-03-05
2024-03-01


EQM1
2024-03-07
2024-03-01


EQM2
2024-03-05
2024-03-05


EQM2
2024-03-06
2024-03-05



In the example "distinct daily serial numbers" would be otherwise 1 except for 2024-03-05 when it would be 2, "all active equipment" would be 1 before 2024-03-05 and then increasing to 2 for upcoming days.
My Attempts
For Measure 1, I used the following expression which works correctly:
Count(DISTINCT serial_number)

For Measure 2, I tried using set analysis to count distinct serial_number where first_signal is on or before the current created_on date. Here's my attempt:
Count({<first_signal={"<= $(=Date(created_on, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))"}>} DISTINCT serial_number)

However, this does not seem to work correctly within the table context, giving incorrect results. The total row gives the correct value, but individual date rows (created_on column) do not.
Any suggestions how to correct my "all active equipment" formula so that it works with when I put created on column as dimension?

This should give the desired result:
Aggr(
    RangeSum(
        Above(
            Aggr(
               Count(distinct "serial_number"),
               "serial_number"),
            0,
            RowNo()
            )
            ),
    (created_on, (Numeric, Ascending))
 )

Screenshot of my result:

Data to reproduce question:
Data:
LOAD serial_number, 
    Date#(created_on, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as created_on, 
    Date#(first_signal, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as first_signal
Inline [
serial_number,  created_on, first_signal
EQM1,   2024-03-01, 2024-03-01
EQM1,   2024-03-02, 2024-03-01
EQM1,   2024-03-05, 2024-03-01
EQM1,   2024-03-07, 2024-03-01
EQM2,   2024-03-05, 2024-03-05
EQM2,   2024-03-06, 2024-03-05
];

